# Views inside views (iOS, Drawing properties)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, interface-builder

Ok, I recognize that I have a complete mess in my mind.

Really, the objective is very simple. I have a little subview inside one of my views (I've added it in Interface Builder). I'm trying to insert inside a little subview that automatically resizes herself to occupy the exact space of his parent view.

```
Controller *c = [[Controller alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:c];
[self.containerView addSubview:self.navigationController.view];
[c release];
```

Controller class contains an UIImageView pretty big. But I've set the properties of the view and the image to 'scale to fill' and size itself properly. However, the image automatically exceeds the area of the view showing bigger and occupying all the window.

Ideas? Thanks a lot!

**Additional:**

After applying meggar's method I have an strange behaviour. The container view is in position 277,176 with a dimensions of 214w,204h. The inserted view is appearing with the same dimensions but translated 100px (aprox.) to the right.

What kind of effect can be causing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setting the view's frame equal to its superview's frame should do the trick, something like:

```
UIView* parentView = self.navigationController.view.superview;
CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(0,0,parentView.frame.size.width,parentView.frame.size.height); 

[self.navigationController.view setFrame:parentView.myFrame ];

[self.containerView addSubview:self.navigationController.view];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Meggar! Works almost perfect, the problem is that the view appears "displaced" 60-80px to the right. Any idea?

I've set a background for the view in order to appreciate it correctly. The view is shown and the image too (but displaced)... :S

Comment: oops.  you actually just want the superview's width and height, not the x and y...  answer edited

Comment: Fantastic Meggar, just fantastic. I am very grateful. Thanks for editing the answer. I have to say that I thought that it was more "automatic".